# How can I send file from local directory to sftp using spring?

Tags: spring, file-upload, sftp

I want to transfer a local file over sftp using Java Spring.

How can I do this? Please provide an example if possible.

Comment: I have used jsch to do this. Google is your friend.

Answer (score 4):

You can refer the example at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/sftp

This has the basic example for

1.Transfers files from remote to local directory

2.Transfers files from local to the remote directory

3.Interact with the remote SFTP server with commands

Note : First functionality is achieved via polling concept

Also Spring SFTP Integration Adapter documentation is available at - http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/sftp.html